# is there a simpler way to group and count with python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am grouping and counting a set of data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A', 'B', 'A'],
                   'data': np.ones(3,)})
df.groupby('key').count()
```

outputs

```
    data
key 
A   2
B   1
```

The piece of code above works though, I wonder if there is a simpler one.

`'data': np.ones(3,)` seems to be a placeholder and indispensable.

```
pd.DataFrame(['A', 'B', 'A']).groupby(0).count()
```

outputs

```
A
B
```

My question is, is there a simpler way to do this, produce the count of 'A' and 'B' respectively, without something like `'data': np.ones(3,)` ?

It doesn't have to be a pandas method, numpy or python native function are also appreciated.

Comment: `df.key.value_counts()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Series` instead.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> data = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D']
>>> 
>>> pd.Series(data).value_counts()
D    5
A    3
C    2
B    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A']

d = defaultdict(int)

for element in data:
    d[element] += 1

d  # output: defaultdict(int, {'A': 4, 'B': 1, 'C': 2})
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not any grouping , just counting, so you can use

```
from collections import Counter
counter(['A', 'B', 'A'])
```